# Proof of Logarithmic Mean and Variance

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification

I'm having some issues proving that the mean of a logarithmic distribution is (-1/(ln(q))) * (p/q) and the variance is -p(((p+ln(q))/ ((q)<sup>2</sup> ln<sup>2</sup> (q))). I have taken the logarithmic distribution, which comes out to be: 
 -log(1-p) = p + p<sup>2</sup>/2 + p<sup>3</sup>/3 + ...
 =

∑<sub>k=1</sub><sup>∞</sup> (-1/(ln(1-p)) * p<sup>k</sup>/k 
 
However, after this step, I'm having issues deriving. Any help into how I could get to the mean and variance?

Comment: What, in a precise nutshell, is the "logarithmic distribution".  Density function, or cdf, please!

Comment: What is $q?$  Is it $1-p?$. At least the mean should be no problem. What is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\times \frac{1}{\ln(1-p)} \; \frac{p^k}{k}?$$ Do you know geometric series?