# Variance with specific PMF

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having issues finding the variance of the following PMF: 
$$\mathbb P(X=k) = C \frac{p^k} k,\quad k=1,2,\ldots$$

where $C$ is a normalizing constant and $p$ is between $0$ and $1$ (inclusive). I have gotten the expected value-- which is $(Cp/q)$ -- but I am having issues calculating the $\operatorname{Var}(X)$, specifically with $E(X^2)$.

Help please?

Comment: Nice to see, that you have done the first part of your old question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448922/proof-of-logarithmic-mean-and-variance). Show your calculations and problems and we may help.

Comment: It appears that you have a created another account to ask part of your question.

Comment: Re: the second moment—can you find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty np^n$? (Recall anything about geometric series and derivatives?)

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X=k)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty C\frac{p^k}k = -C\log(1-p),
$$
and hence $C = -\frac1{\log(1-p)}$. We compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X^2] &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty -\frac1{\log(1-p)}kp^k\\
&= -\frac {p}{\log(1-p)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)p^k\\
&= -\frac {p}{\log(1-p)(1-p)^2},
\end{align}
and hence
\begin{align}
\mathsf{Var}(X) &= \mathbb E\left[X^2\right] - \mathbb E[X]^2\\
&= \frac {p}{\log(1-p)(1-p)^2} - \left(-\frac{p}{\log(1-p)(1-p)}\right)^2\\
&= \frac {p}{\log(1-p)(1-p)^2} - \frac{p^2}{\log(1-p)^2(1-p)^2}\\
&= \frac{p(\log(1-p)-p)}{(\log(1-p)(1-p))^2}.
\end{align}